# Как получить миниатюры (thumbnails) файлов?

Tags: python, windows, иконки

В виндоус при выборе режима просмотра файлов в папке "Крупные значки" файлы отображаются миниатюрами.

Можно ли как-то с помощью питона получить все эти миниатюры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте этот пакет [preview-generator](https://pypi.org/project/preview-generator/#:~:text=preview%2Dgenerator%5Bdrawio%5D-,3D%20files%20(VTK),-warning%3A)

Comment: При отображении миниатюр в папке создается скрытый файл Thumbs.db (на новых версиях Windows файл может называться по-другому), в нем сами миниатюры и хранятся. Теоретически его можно распарсить. Попробуйте вот этот модуль, например: https://github.com/AtesComp/Vinetto

Comment: Но это правда не поможет, если папку еще не открывали в режиме миниатюр.